# If module 'example' contains both function 'run' and submodule 'run', can I count on 'from example import run' to always import the former?

Tags: python

If I have a Python module implemented as a directory (i.e. package) that has both a top level function `run` and a submodule `run`, can I count on `from example import run` to always import the function? Based on my tests that is the case at least with Python 2.6 and Jython 2.5 on Linux, but can I count on this generally? I tried to search information about the import priorities but couldn't find anything.

Background:

I have a pretty large package that people generally run as a tool from the command line but also sometimes use programmatically. I would like to have simple entry points for both usages and consider to implement them like this:

`example/__init__.py`:

```
def run(*args):
    print args  # real application code belongs here
```

`example/run.py`:

```
import sys
from example import run
run(*sys.argv[1:])
```

The first entry point allows users to access the module from Python like this:

```
from example import run
run(args)
```

The latter entry point allows users to execute the module from the command line using both of the approaches below:

```
python -m example.run args
python path/to/example/run.py args
```

This both works great and covers everything I need. Before taking this into real use, I would like to know is this a sound approach that I can expect to work with all Python implementations on all operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should always work; the function definition will shadow the module.

However, this also strikes me as a dirty hack. The clean way to do this would be

```
# __init__.py
# re-export run.run as run
from .run import run
```

i.e., a minimal `__init__.py`, with all the running logic in `run.py`:

```
# run.py
def run(*args):
    print args  # real application code belongs here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Only way this wouldn't work would be if for some crazy reason you do the import after you define the function something like:                                                  def a():
    pass

import a as a

Comment: Good point, organizing the code like this is cleaner. I need to think does it work with some other constraints I have. Good to also know that the function definition always shadows the module if I need to use that approach.